# jQuery onkeyup method not defined

Tags: jquery, key-events

the onkeyup method is supposedly not defined, however, the method is auto-recommended to me by my ide. When I view the error in chrome dev tools I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onkeyup'. I am using the latest version of jQuery. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
                $.post("addName.php", {q: str});
            });
            $("input").onkeyup(function(){
                var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
                $.post("gethint.php", {q: str});
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
<form action="">
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
<button> Add Name</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("input").on('keyup', function(){
    var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    $.post("gethint.php", {q: str});
});
```

or

```
$("input").keyup( function(){
    var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    $.post("gethint.php", {q: str});
});
```

jQuery has no method name `onkeyup`

Read more about **[`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** and **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. I am using $.post correctly, right? Because now that the event is being triggered, I don't think the script is still ever being run :/ I know this because the echoes I have at the top of the file are never output.

Comment: Just wondering why you would use:
var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
instead of:
var str = $('#txt1').val();
Since you are using Jquery

Answer (score 1):

The method is:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of onkeyup use keyup

```
 $("input").keyup(function(){
                var str = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
                $.post("gethint.php", {q: str});
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `onkeyup` doesn't exist, the error message clearly says `"onkeyup method not defined"`. It should be just [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    //Your code
});
```